# Can't pass variable outside the scope of a Sequalize promise

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Here is a bit of code to demonstrate my issue.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Game = sequelize.define('Game', { ... }, {
    tableName: 'games',
    instanceMethods: {
      getState: function(userClass) {
        var currentGame = this;
        var gameState = {};

        userClass.findOne({ where: { id: currentGame.challenger_user_id }}).then(
          function(challengerUser) {
            userClass.findOne({ where: { id: currentGame.recipient_user_id }}).then(
              function(recipientUser) {
                var turn;
                if (currentGame.turn_symbol == 'X') {
                  turn = { user: challengerUser, symbol: 'X' };
                } else {
                  turn = { user: recipientUser, symbol: 'O' };
                }

                gameState.game = currentGame;
                gameState.turn = turn;
                gameState.participants = [
                  { user: challengerUser, symbol: 'X' },
                  { user: recipientUser, symbol: 'O' }
                ];

                console.log(gameState);
                // Shows the object with the assigned values
              }
            );
          }
        );

        console.log(gameState)
        // Shows an empty object.
      }
    },
    classMethods: { ... }
  });
  return Game;
};
```

In the `getState` function, we first declare an empty object named `gameState`.

We then find two users -- so we're now nested within two scopes -- and try to assign a value to our `gameState` variable.

When doing a console.log within the two nested scopes, the object is shown with all of the assigned values.

`gameState` is shown to be an empty object when doing a console.log outside of the two nested scopes (after assigning values).

Can someone help explain my error here?

Also, what is the correct term for these nested scopes -- are they promises?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "Sequalize"?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function.

Comment: @torazaburo if you post that link as an answer, I'll mark you as correct. That link answered a question I was also curious about (but didn't ask here) in regards to returning a value from an asynch operation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I thought of a possible solution immediately after writing the question.

The reason why the `console.log(gameState)` at the end of the `getState` function returns null is because it runs asynchronous to the sequelize promises.

In other words, the server took .05 milliseconds to get to the last `console.log(gameState)`, but the server took .15 milliseconds to get to where values are assigned to it.

^ Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Things that happen in the future do not happen in the present.